# Deploying web app on live server. 404 not found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

**1.What I am trying to do:**

My question concerns the implementation of Dynamic Web Project on live server.
How do I make a web application that works locally, will work on a live server?

**2 What I did:**

**The steps I have taken:**

1. Create Java App in Eclipse (using Servlet, Tomcat)

   My very simple, test code:

   ```
   package com.test;    
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   @WebServlet("/HelloWorld")

   public class Test extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       out.print("Hello World");
   }
   ```

   }
2. Export of the war file
3. Uploaded my Java WAR package to my public_html directory.
   (I don't have access to any manager who could support my implementations, the only way is to connect to the server via SSH/FTP and upload a .war file to public_html)
4. Run the unzip to extract the package.
5. Added the. htaccess file with following text:
   SetHandler Jakar-servlet
   SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13

**3 What is not working?**

By passing this url:
http:///~(myusername)/Test/HelloWorld

ERROR:
Not Found
The requested URL /~(myusername)/Test/HelloWorld was not found on this server.

Apparently I don't fully understand the subject of implementation on the server, I swear that I tried to look for an answer, but now I'm in the trap, I can't move on.

Comment: As watching to your Servlet class there will no line gap between Servlet annotation and Servlet class name, also you can take a help from my recent answer on simple servlet example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139947/404-error-servlet/48140320#48140320

Comment: Are you sure the server is running a JEE web container? Your description of the deployment process does not sound like it would.

Comment: @Henry, how can i check it?
In the application, everything works after  (I mean locally):                           http: //localhost:8080/Test/HelloWorld

Comment: "how can i check it?": the easiest way is to ask the person or organization that runs the server.

Comment: @Henry: OP is using a so-called "cPanel" based host. This is at least not a programming problem and therefore off topic for Stack Overflow.